# Getting the AccessToken by using OAuth2S2SClient returns "Token Request failed"?

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, ms-office, exchangewebservices, office365

I'm trying to create the Sharepoint ClientContext to get the list of documents from sharpoint online.
to do this I'm using the TokenHelper.cs class.
If you have not seen the class, the code which returns the sharepoint context looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses the specified access token to create a client context
/// </summary>
/// <param name="targetUrl">Url of the target SharePoint site</param>
/// <param name="accessToken">Access token to be used when calling the specified targetUrl</param>
/// <returns>A ClientContext ready to call targetUrl with the specified access token</returns>
public static ClientContext GetClientContextWithAccessToken(string targetUrl, string accessToken)
  {
    Uri targetUri = new Uri(targetUrl);
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetUrl);

    clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Anonymous;
    clientContext.FormDigestHandlingEnabled = false;
    clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest +=
              delegate(object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs)
                {
                    webRequestEventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] =
                        "Bearer " + accessToken;
                };
    return clientContext;
  }
```

but before calling this method I need to get an access token, to do this I'm using the following method from the TokenHelper class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses the specified authorization code to retrieve an access token from ACS to call the specified principal 
/// at the specified targetHost. The targetHost must be registered for target principal.  If specified realm is 
/// null, the "Realm" setting in web.config will be used instead.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="authorizationCode">Authorization code to exchange for access token</param>
/// <param name="targetPrincipalName">Name of the target principal to retrieve an access token for</param>
/// <param name="targetHost">Url authority of the target principal</param>
/// <param name="targetRealm">Realm to use for the access token's nameid and audience</param>
/// <returns>An access token with an audience of the target principal</returns>
public static OAuth2AccessTokenResponse GetAccessToken(string authorizationCode, string targetPrincipalName, string targetHost, string targetRealm, Uri redirectUri)
   {
     if (targetRealm == null)
     {
       targetRealm = Realm;
     }

     string resource = GetFormattedPrincipal(targetPrincipalName, targetHost, targetRealm);
     string clientId = GetFormattedPrincipal(ClientId, null, targetRealm);

     // Create request for token. The RedirectUri is null here.  This will fail if redirect uri is registered
     OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request = OAuth2MessageFactory.CreateAccessTokenRequestWithAuthorizationCode(clientId, ClientSecret, authorizationCode, redirectUri, resource);

     // Get token
     OAuth2S2SClient client = new OAuth2S2SClient();
     OAuth2AccessTokenResponse oauth2Response;
     try
       {
         oauth2Response = client.Issue(AcsMetadataParser.GetStsUrl(targetRealm), oauth2Request) as OAuth2AccessTokenResponse;
       }
     catch (WebException wex)
       {
         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
           string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
           throw new WebException(wex.Message + " - " + responseText, wex);
         }
       }
 return oauth2Response;
 }
```

when I trace my code I can see the following line throws an exception:

oauth2Response = client.Issue(AcsMetadataParser.GetStsUrl(targetRealm), oauth2Request) as OAuth2AccessTokenResponse;

Token request failed.
HResult: -2146233088
Source: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions
Inner exception: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are passing the correct parameters to the method, I was able to get access token using this method with little trial and error. My method call signature is

```
var accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(authCode, "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", targetUri.Authority, realm, redirectUri).AccessToken;
```

authorizationCode is what you get when successfully authenticated with SharePoint and redirected to your application page.

```
string authCode = Request["code"];
```

targetPrincipalName is a constant.

targetHost is like "tenant.sharepoint.com"

realm is obtained as follows(this is a constant you can reuse within your tenancy):

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri("https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>");
string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(targetUri)
```

redirect uri is the uri of the current page without any query strings.

```
redirectUri = new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path))
```

see this article for more details.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples that are available on MSDN Download Gallery that you can pull down and test against your tenant that have been already confirmed as working. I would recommend pulling down one of these examples to prove its not something in your code and write off that it isn't your tenant environment either. 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-2013-Sample-81b03d1e